# Apache ProxyPass mapping working, Rewrite rule for it not working

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, proxypass

I put this lines into `httpd.conf` file for Apache 2.2:

```
ProxyPass        /api/post    http://localhost:8082/DE_API/post
ProxyPassReverse /api/post    http://localhost:8082/DE_API/post
RewriteRule      /api/upload  /api/post
```

Then the following request is correctly mapped:

```
http://mydomain.com/api/post
```

this other does not work:

```
http://mydomain.com/api/upload
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
RewriteRule      /api/upload  /api/post
```

to

```
RewriteRule      ^api/upload  /api/post [L,NC]
```

From: [RewriteRule Directive <sup>Apache docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

So, do not start a pattern with `/` when matching in `RewriteRule`.